# How to get size of a response coming from json array

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

I've a json response in which I've stored some data and now I want to get the size of the json objects present in json array

```
[
    {
        "type": "Insurance Policies",
        "count": 2,
        "category_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "type": "Mediclaim Policies",
        "count": 1,
        "category_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "type": "Mutual Fund Policies",
        "count": 1,
        "category_id": "3"
    }
]
```

Comment: List size is JsonArray Size if you are using and auto parser .. If you are parsing manually then `jsonArray.length()`.

Comment: Okay, I got the answer I just needed to create the object of JSONArray and store the response in that object and just need to call object.length()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got the answer I just needed to create the object of JSONArray and store the response in that object and just need to call object.length()

Answer (score 0):

Use below code for getting JSON Array Length

```
String jsonStringContent = [
    {
        "type": "Insurance Policies",
        "count": 2,
        "category_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "type": "Mediclaim Policies",
        "count": 1,
        "category_id": "2"
    },
    {
        "type": "Mutual Fund Policies",
        "count": 1,
        "category_id": "3"
    }
];

JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStringContent);

int size = jsonArray.length();
```